# Inner class Factory Method

Tags: vb.net

I have tried to implement the Factory method with a trick, but for some reason is not working:

```
Public Class MetamodelElement
Public Class MetamodelElementFactoryBase
End Class

Private Sub New()
End Sub

End Class

Public Class MetamodelElementFactory : Inherits MetamodelElement.MetamodelElementFactoryBase
    Function CreateMetamodelElement() As MetamodelElement
        Return New MetamodelElement()
    End Function

End Class
```

It says that the class does not have access to the private method (constructor).

I have followed an example from C# in this post:
[Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c/1399045#1399045)

Comment: _"but for some reason"_ any chance that you tell us the compiler error?

Comment: You're right, I should have been more precise. I have edited the question.

Comment: 'Inner class Factory Method' => you need to move Public Class MetamodelElementFactory inside Public Class MetamodelElement

Comment: or add a Protected method CreateMetamodelElement()in Public Class MetamodelElementFactoryBase and call _that_ from MetamodelElementFactory, Which is the paradigm being shown in th linked c# example

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains that you are trying to use the `Private` constructor from outside of the class. That is not allowed. So either make it `Public` or don't call it.

```
Public Class MetamodelElement
    Public Class MetamodelElementFactoryBase
    End Class

    Public Sub New()  ' <---- HERE!!! Now it works because it's public
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MetamodelElementFactory
    Inherits MetamodelElement.MetamodelElementFactoryBase

    Function CreateMetamodelElement() As MetamodelElement
        Return New MetamodelElement() ' <--- HERE was the error
    End Function

End Class
```

You can access private class members only from inside of the class.

[MSDN: Access Levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx)

---

According to the [C# code that you've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c/1399045#1399045) you have to move the constructor into the class that you are inheriting from. Then you can also use `Protected`:

```
Public Class MetamodelElement
    Public Class MetamodelElementFactoryBase
        Protected Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```